# How to fix LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out?

Tags: exception, solr, spring-data-solr

My integration tests are failing when I run them from a Gradle task.

```
org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: **SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher; nested exception is org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher**
at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:122)
at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveDocuments(SolrTemplate.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveDocuments(SolrTemplate.java:201)
```

**org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/opt/solr/example/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock**

When I run the integration tests directly in Intellij, the tests run successfully. Here is my bean definition for the embedded server. I added the destroyMethod and it had no effect.

```
 @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public SolrServer solrServer(org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration configuration)  {

    EmbeddedSolrServerFactory factory;
    try {
        factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactory(configuration.getString("solr.home"));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
        String errorMsg = "Encountered an exception while initializing the SolrServer bean.";
        log.error(errorMsg, e);
        throw new OrdersClientRuntimeException(errorMsg, e);
    }
    return factory.getSolrServer();
}
```

Here are the logs. Everything seems to be shutting down correctly.

```
2014-09-02 17:32:15.757 thread="Thread-6" level="DEBUG" logger="o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter" - **Invoking destroy method 'shutdown' on bean with name 'solrServer'**
2014-09-02 17:32:15.759 thread="Thread-8" level="DEBUG" logger="o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory" - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'solrDocumentRepository': [net.nike.orders.client.search.repository.DocumentRepositorySpec]
2014-09-02 17:32:15.759 thread="Thread-6" level="INFO " logger="org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer" - **Shutting down CoreContainer instance=179265569**
2014-09-02 17:32:15.760 thread="Thread-8" level="DEBUG" logger="o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter" - **Invoking destroy method 'shutdown' on bean with name 'solrServer'**
2014-09-02 17:32:15.760 thread="Thread-8" level="INFO " logger="org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer" - **Shutting down CoreContainer instance=1604485329**
2014-09-02 17:32:15.762 thread="Thread-6" level="INFO " logger="org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore" - [collection1]  **CLOSING SolrCore** org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@28da98e2
2014-09-02 17:32:15.769 thread="Thread-8" level="DEBUG" logger="o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager" - **Connection manager is shutting down**
2014-09-02 17:32:15.769 thread="Thread-6" level="INFO " logger="**org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler" - closing** DirectUpdateHandler2{commits=23,autocommit maxTime=15000ms,autocommits=0,soft autocommits=2,optimizes=0,rollbacks=0,expungeDeletes=0,docsPending=0,adds=0,deletesById=0,deletesByQuery=0,errors=0,cumulative_adds=33,cumulative_deletesById=32,cumulative_deletesByQuery=0,cumulative_errors=0,transaction_logs_total_size=5302,transaction_logs_total_number=10}
2014-09-02 17:32:15.771 thread="Thread-8" level="DEBUG" logger="o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager" - Connection manager shut down
2014-09-02 17:32:15.773 thread="Thread-8" level="DEBUG" logger="o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager" - Connection manager is shutting down
2014-09-02 17:32:15.774 thread="Thread-8" level="DEBUG" logger="o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager" - Connection manager shut down
```

Here is my environment information:

- Linux Mint 17
- Solr 4.9.0
- Solr Test Framework 4.9.0
- Oracle Java 1.7
- Spring Data Solr 1.2.2.RELEASE
- IntelliJ 13.1.4
- Gradle 1.12
- Tests are developed in Spock

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing with my tests but the unlockOnStartup flag didn't work for me. I ended up changing the lock type (and leaving unlockOnStartup commented out):

```
<lockType>${solr.lock.type:single}</lockType>
<!--<unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>-->
```

The note on the default lock type (native) makes me think that I don't the server shutting down cleany between test runs but I haven't been able to find it yet :(

```
         native = NativeFSLockFactory - uses OS native file locking.
                  Do not use when multiple solr webapps in the same
                  JVM are attempting to share a single index.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue and got it fixed.

I use the `EmbeddedSolrServer` in my unit tests and dynamically create new cores during runtime.

When creating the `CoreContainer` be sure to call shutdown() after the tests.

Also be sure all `SolrCore` instances are closed after your tests.

Calling `coreContainer.create(CoreDescriptor, name, ...)` opens a SolrCore which you have to close manually.

When creating the `EmbeddedSolrServer` by passing the coreName, the SolrCore is not opened! Open and close is handled by the `EmbeddedSolrServer` for each request/action.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I was able to fix the issue by changing

```
<unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>
```

in the solrconfig.xml file.